# Laravel 5 : How to retrieve records according to date?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a table called `entries` and its `created_at` is defined as `DATE` type. How do I get a record, for example, of 15 March?

---

**What I've tried**

```
        $post = Entry::where(\DB::raw('DATE(created_at)'),'=',date('2015-03-15'))->get()->toJSON();
```

but it returns empty result.

---

**Migration**

```
    Schema::create('entries', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('intern_id');
        $table->integer('company_id');
        $table->longText('content');
        $table->date('created_at')->unique();
        $table->date('updated_at')->unique();
    });
```

There are currently 3 records with dates of each of `2015-03-15`, `2015-03-19` and `2015-03-20`

Comment: Can we see some sample data? Also what is the table migration for Entry?

Comment: @Chris question edited as requested.

Comment: Can you try: `Entry::where('created_at', '>=', '2015-03-15 00:00:00')->get()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
$post = Entry::where("created_at","2015-03-15")->get()->toJSON();
```

Comment: It still returns an empty result. Here is the SQL: `select * from 'entries' where 'created_at' = 2015-03-15`

Comment: However, when I add the `>=` sign in between, it returns only the most recent record when it should have returned all 3 records as all 3 records have their dates >= to 15 March.

Comment: whats ur data type for `created_date` ?

Comment: Hey, update your answer to the original and I'll mark yours as the correct one. I went to your original answer and tried it out again and it worked. I think I retyped yours wrongly at first. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this form:

```
$post = Entry::where('created_at', '>=', '2015-03-15')->get()->toJSON();
```

**Carbon Update**

```
    $date = \Carbon\Carbon::create(2015, 3, 13, 0, 0, 0);

    $u = Entry::where('created_at', '>=', (string) $date)
        ->where('created_at', '<', (string) $date->addDays(1))
        ->get()
        ->toJSON();
```

Comment: It only gets the latest record dated `2015-03-20`. It should have gotten all 3 records, right? Anyway, I only want to get a record which is dated `2015-03-15`

Comment: For records equaling, you might need to add an additional clause, because dates are stored as timestamps in laravel. So `>= 2015-03-15 00:00:00` and `<= 2015-03-15 23:59:99`. But if you start doing something like this, it''s time to look at Carbon

Comment: Well, I'll be happy if you can update your answer in Carbon. ;)